# Vacuum pressure sensor for Arduino

Tags: sensors

I have an application that is being controlled by an Arduino. At one point in the process, it needs to determine the level of vacuum in a chamber and adjust it to within a range of values.

I can control the vacuum pumps easily enough, but it is hard to find a vacuum sensor for the Arduino. I need a sensor that can be reasonably accurate down to roughly 28 inches mercury and would connect by a tube. I can't put the sensor directly into the chamber.

Does anyone know of an Arduino sensor that would work? If not, could someone suggest a sensor component that may work with an Arduino. I would prefer to not have to engineer a solution from the sensor component up but I can if I need to.

Comment: Is that 94.8 kPa? So it is just a slightly below the normal baromic pressure?

Comment: A bmp280 can measure 300...1100 hPa.

Comment: @Jot Inches of mercury are a negative scale. The greater the number the closer to a perfect vacuum. 28 inches Hg is just short of the level of vacuum created by a good commercial vacuum pump you would use for fiberglass infusion.

Comment: Then how many absolute hPa is it?

Comment: I would need to check this, but roughly 29.8 inHg is close to max mechanically achievable vacuum. Basicly the pressure difference between normal atmouspheric perssure and an empty volume of space.

Comment: I just did a conversion and 28 inches mercury came out to aprox 950 hPa. I am unfamiliar with that scale so I don't know if I made a mistake. I need to be able to measure the level of vacuum in a very evacuated cylinder. This is for degassing epoxy resin mixtures

Comment: It is not an absolute value then, but a differential value? That is a little weird for me, for very low pressures a absolute value makes more sense. The "normal" pressure or vacuum sensors are 3V or 5V sensor with amplifier and temperature compensation from nxp.com. Search for vacuum sensors. For example the MPXV6115V. For more sensors search at mouse.com for pressure sensor, and then select one of the vacuum types. I see some Honeywell sensors, but they are 15V.

Comment: Ok, a quick check on my vacuum gauges and I can see that I need to measure down to roughly -92 kPa. The MPXV6115V seems to handle this range fine and works over a 5v range. That may be the solution. I was really hoping there would be a mass-produced Arduino shield for this, but worst case I can work with that sensor. Thanks @Jot

Comment: That sensor is ratiometric, you should power it with the 5v pin of the arduino. A arduino uno has 10-bits adc, that is good enough for the 1.5% error of the MPXV6115V. Take a few samples and calculate the average. I think that will work. The biggest problem is soldering something to the small pins. Never connect something to the unused pins of the sensor. The unused pins can be connected to something inside.

Comment: 10 bits resolution with an error of +/- 1.5% would be more than enough for what I will be doing. My bigger concern would be hysteresis in the sensor but I am guessing that shouldn't be an issue. I still wish this was in an off the shelf shield, but I can't have everything. Looks like I will need to hone my SMD soldering skills.

Comment: Most industrial vacuum/pressure sensors do not specify which sensor is inside. I suppose this sensor is used in a metal case with a price of about 100 dollars. Perhaps with extra electronics for a voltage of 24v and a current loop output. I have never noticed any hysteresis with these kind of sensors. Just a little noise, that's all.

Comment: @Jot If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it. I have ordered the parts and it looks like it will do what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industrial pressure/vacuum sensors are sturdy and rigid. They have extra protection, for example to use it submersible. The manufacturer often make them for certain voltages (for example 24v) and with different outputs (0..5v output, or 5-20ma output, and so on).
There are cheap versions of those sensors. They are between 5 and 20 dollars on Ebay and Aliexpress.
The manufacturers do not tell which sensor they use inside, and it can be hard to find a sensor that is exactly the one that you need.

The bare sensor is often a piezoresistive sensor in a wheatstone bride configuration. The output voltage span of those sensors is very low and not suitable to connect directly to an arduino board.
The advantage can be that they do not have a operating voltage. Only a maximum voltage.

The ideal pressure/vacuum sensor has a temperature compensation and a gain and a output span that is near 5v. You find most of them at nxp.com.
Luckely they have also a vacuum sensor with a large range, for example the MPXV6115V.

Those sensors are ratiometric. Power them with the arduino 5v and use the arduino 5v as analog reference (that is the Arduino default setting). When the 5v changes, the resulting measured pressure does not change and is still accurate.

Never solder something to the unused pins. Those pins can be connected to something inside.

There are a few ways to calculate the pressure. One way is to use the formula from the datasheet, the other way is to map the output voltage span to the pressure span and correct for the offset of the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have 4 of these sensors on order and will be testing them out. They look spot on for my application. I wish they were a shield, but I can't get everything.